# A question about implementing I/O double buffering in C#

Tags: c#, buffer

I'm planning to do some real time 2D grayscale image acquisition. In my case the program will receive a 1D array from a line scan camera one by one. Then the program will construct the image from these arrays(forming a bitmap  matrix from arrays). But since buffering and processing/drawing are in series, for large data the frame rate will be very slow.

After reading some articles, I noticed to speed up the frame rate many are using buffers such as double buffer. Below illustrates the concept:

[image]

But I am very confused because when I do search for "double buffering C#" another type of thing comes up which is about preventing flickering in WinForms.

What I am looking for is an algorithm, class or library implementation in C# which allocates two buffers(one for I/O other for processing) and performs double buffering. I cannot find any example for such sort of double buffering in C#.

Comment: Double buffering is generally a term used as you also state for reducing flickering, by showing one framebuffer while pushing data into another and switching them around when ready.

But to solve your challenge, it might be worth knowing a bit more about how fast you receive scan lines, compared to how fast you can map them from 1D to 2D. If you receive scanlines much faster, then push them onto a queue and let a thread pool, pull them from the queue for processing and view presentation. But I think we need a bit more info, in order to give you directions on the most optimal solution.

Comment: Can you give ma hint about the queue? Should I look for Queue<T> Class in C#? Never used that. Actually at the moment I cannot quantify but assuming scanlines will be received at kHz speed(each line will be max around 4096 size byte or uint16 1D array and I want to see the frames min 6 frame per second. For large data the screen updates much slower its because during each buffering the screen stays still waiting for the data. So double buffer would speed up that process. I couldn't find an example such as Console example.

Comment: There might be some inspiration to find in etc. https://www.dotnetcurry.com/dotnetcore/1509/async-dotnetcore-pattern which talks about the 3 most common ways of implementing a Producer Consumer pattern.

It might help you getting started, and help you along the way if you need to write a faster implementation specifically for you need.